# signal sigabrt delegate -> AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

First, I apologise for this probably somewhat easy/noobish question.
However, I've been trying to debug this error for quite a while now. Unfortunately without luck, I recently started working in Xcode and using Swift.

I have been following a tutorial from Udemy, a online course.
However, after inserting the code, I keep getting this error:

```
Thread1: Signal SIGABRT
```

No idea what is could be. I have been looking on google 
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/error-message-thread-1-signal-sigabrt-in-class-appdelegate

But this did not solve my problem :(

Also, it is very difficult to understand what exactly is happening, so I can't find a good solution through google. Maybe you can help me out.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var statePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statePickerBtn: UIButton!

    let states = ["Alaska","Arkansas","Alabama","California","New York"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.statePicker.dataSource = self
        statePicker.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func stateBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        statePickerBtn.isHidden = false
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return states.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return states[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        statePickerBtn.setTitle(states[row], for: UIControlState.application)
        statePicker.isHidden = true
    }
```

What am I trying to do:
I have a picker on hidden, when the user press the button, I want it to reveal the picker. Once users click on the event, they will see the picker with the array. Well, you know what I mean. However, when I build it, the simulator remains white and Xcode prompts me to AppDelegate.Swift with this specific error.

Tnx

[Print screen of the error after I pressed Run. + Output, sorry for messy prnt scrn :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzw8w.png)

Console Output:

```
2017-03-01 18:03:39.717795 myPillsNoob[969:17168] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-01 18:03:39.725996 myPillsNoob[969:17168] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-01 18:03:39.738908 myPillsNoob[969:17165] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-01 18:03:39.760737 myPillsNoob[969:17069] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-01 18:03:39.849 myPillsNoob[969:17069] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<myPillsNoob.ViewController 0x7fa24ce09160> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key stateButtonPressed.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001132e234b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011038f21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001132e2299 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010fe9f2ff -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001109f88c3 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000110c6cbe6 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113287590 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000110c6b56a -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001109feff5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001109ff917 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001109ffc4c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000110a004a0 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001108ca045 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001108ca796 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001108de0a9 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000110857259 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    16  UIKit                               0x000000011085d3b9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    17  UIKit                               0x000000011085a539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011477b76b __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011477b5e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011477b96d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113287311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011326c59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011326ba86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011326b494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000110858db6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    26  UIKit                               0x000000011085ef34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  myPillsNoob                         0x000000010fdb071f main + 111
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000113fe568d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Is there anything more - console or Xcode - to help us? That's a very generic error. But, the details of the error should pretty much point to the issue.

Comment: Where exactly can I find what you need? The console remains empty. I am used to write software in visual studio and I started Xcode 2 days ago. Kinda confused

Comment: I wrote in VS for about 15 years until 2015 also, so I understand your pain. :-) I'm assuming Xcode doesn't just "stop" on a line of code. (If it is, please point out which line.) Beyond that, two things: (1) Menu option View | Debug Area | Activate Console. (2) Click directly on the SIGABRT error in the left hand column. (You'll see an extremely messy dump, but it would help.)

Comment: You can also just copy the entire error window output when you press Run, and something in there might tip us off.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/yCbZ2 print screen of the entire window output after pressing run. + all output. When I right click on "Thread1:Signal SIGABRT"   -> find definition it returns a question mark. Really no idea how to debug in this editor o.o

Comment: Additionally to the error, in the action function of the button you write  `statePickerBtn.isHidden = false`. However, if you want the picker to appear, you have to write `statePicker.isHidden = false`

Comment: @McLawrence Oh thanks you're right,  didn't see that one, since I can't test/run it for now:P

Comment: On your print-screen... at lower-right... see the numbered lines going from 14 to 29? The answer is up at (and a bit above) line number 1

Comment: @DonMag Posted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most significant error information is:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key stateButtonPressed.

- Press <kbd>⇧⌘F</kbd>.
- Search for `stateButtonPressed`. It's most likely a dead connection in Interface Builder.
- Remove the connection.

Comment: Thanks alot! Could you maybe tell me how this is possible? I did exactly like in the course, control drag it into the code. How can this go wrong exactly? Also, I apologise for not being able to give you a +1 since I do not have the required reputation to upvote :(

Comment: Probably you had once a method `stateButtonPressed` and made a connection in Interface Builder. Then you renamed the method in the view controller to `stateBtnPressed`. That broke the connection.

Comment: I was breaking my head until you mentioned about dead connection @vadian :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see if you have any unintended connection to your object is to look at each of the object you created in the Main Storyboard. Once you select the object you built, look at the most right panel, click on the circle with right arrow symbol (the last one), You will see "Referencing Outlets". Make sure it lists only the connection(s) to View Controller that you want -- it should only be one connection per object for basic applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this line in the output:

> 2017-03-01 18:03:39.849 myPillsNoob[969:17069] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key stateButtonPressed.'

It's telling you that something in your app is trying to set the property / variable / key `stateButtonPressed` in your `myPillsNoob.ViewController` class, but that `key` is not there.

The most common reason is that you at some point added an IBOutlet reference in Interface Builder, and then deleted that `IBOutlet` line in your code.

Edit: One common cause...

1. Ctrl+Drag from a UIButton into code
2. Type "stateButtonPressed"
3. Notice that I forgot to change the Connection dropdown from "Outlet" to "Action"
4. Delete the `@IBOutlet weak var stateButtonPressed: UIButton!` line that was just added
5. Ctrl+Drag from the button again, this time selecting Action to auto-generate my IBAction function
6. And...... I now have a button that wants an IBOutlet that is no longer there.

At least, that's what I do :)

Comment: I dont recall that I removed any IBOutlet, but thanks alot for the explanation. Unfortunately I can not upvote your answer as I do not have the required reputation to do so.

Comment: @Niklaus - I edited my answer... Not saying that's what you did, but it might save you a headache in the future.

Comment: Probably exactly what has happened!